# Java shutdown hook implementation

Tags: java

I'm looking for examples how to implement a shutdown handler correctly in Java. Consider the code below. The application runs as a daemon in the background. When the OS sends SIGTERM to the app, it has to perform cleanup tasks. The question is how to notify the main thread in `App.java` when all tasks finished.

The code below does not work because `component.isRunning.wait();` is called from a static method. Could someone give me some advice how to do it on a nice way?

App.java

```
package myapp;

public class App {

    final static int processorToRun=8;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        //init component
        SoftwareComponent component=new SoftwareComponent(processorToRun);

        //start component
        component.start();

        //set shutdown hook to handle SIGTERM
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(getShutdownHandler(component));


        //wait until the shutdown handler stops the component
        synchronized (component.isRunning) {
            while(component.isRunning) {
                component.isRunning.wait();
            }
        }

    }

    private static Thread getShutdownHandler(SoftwareComponent component) {
        Thread handler=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (component.isRunning) {
                    component.stop();
                    component.isRunning.notify();
                }
            }
        };
        return handler;
    }
}
```

SoftwareComponent.java

```
package myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SoftwareComponent {
    Boolean isRunning=true;
    private List<Processor>processors=new ArrayList<Processor>();

    public SoftwareComponent(int processorsToRun) {
        //init component

        for(int i=0;i<processorsToRun;i++) {
            processors.add(new Processor("Processor-"+i));
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        processors.forEach(processor->new Thread(processor).start());
    }

    public void stop() {
        processors.forEach(processor->processor.stop());
        isRunning=false;
    }

    public Boolean getIsRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
}
```

Processor.java

```
package myapp;

public class Processor implements Runnable{

    Boolean keepRunning=true;
    Boolean processingFinished;
    String  processorName;
    public Processor(String name) {
        //Init processor
        this.processorName=name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(keepRunning) {
            //do some cool stuff
            System.out.println(processorName+"is working.");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        keepRunning=false;
        System.out.println(processorName+" stopped");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Processor-0is working.
Processor-2is working.
Processor-4is working.
Processor-5is working.
Processor-3is working.
Processor-1is working.
Processor-7is working.
Processor-6is working.

CTRL-C pressed here

Processor-0 stopped
Processor-1 stopped
Processor-2 stopped
Processor-3 stopped
Processor-4 stopped
Processor-5 stopped
Processor-6 stopped
Processor-7 stopped
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at myapp.App$1.run(App.java:34)
```

Comment: `synchronized (component.isRunning)` is really not a good idea - you are synchronizing on a mutable reference (and to make it worse, on a global static constant, i.e. `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`). `synchronized (component)` would certainly work better.

Comment: I don't think you should be synchronizing on `component.isRunning`. Once you call `component.stop()`, you change the value of `component.isRunning`. That's why you are getting the exception, since you are notifying an object that you aren't synchronized on. Try synchronizing on just `component`.

Comment: And `keepRunning` should probably be a `private volatile boolean`.

Comment: @abernardi597 Thank you, too, now I know why it did not work.